# What is the difference between a phosphoryl group and a phosphate group?

Tags: nomenclature, organophosphorus-compounds

I am looking at covalent modification of enzymes and I found out that only one of these types is phosphorylation. But I do not understand what the difference between the a phosphate and a phosphoryl group is in terms of nomenclature.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoryl_group

Comment: @Mithoron It simply says "phosphoryl group should not be confused with a phosphate group." , but does not explain why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is basically one oxygen atom. If you consider monoethyl phosphate as an example, the ethyl alpha-carbon bears a phosphate group, whereas the ethoxy oxygen bears a phosphoryl group.

[image]

Comment: I added a diagram for you, feel free to elaborate on it if you want.

Comment: your diagrams they both look pretty much the same just some different colours. But looking https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoryl_group  I see they look quite different. e.g. different number of oxygens.

Answer (score 2):

**Phosphates** are esters of phosophoric acid, $\ce{HO-P(O)(OH)2}$, when one or more its $\ce{OH}$ groups are replaced by (substituded) alkyloxy (alkoxy) groups. E.g. Ethyl phosphate, $\ce{CH3CH2-O-P(O)(OH)2}$. In biochemistry, where the ‘alkyls’ are very complicated, the names are based on the alcohols: ethanol phosphate.

A compendium of various IUPAC books info, IUPAC Gold Book, lacks ‘**phosphoryl**’ term, however, for ‘[phosphorylation](https://goldbook.iupac.org/html/P/PT06790.html)’, states:

> **phosphorylation**
>
> A process (catalysed by enzymes) involving the transfer of a phosphate group from a donor to a suitable acceptor; in general, an ester linkage is formed (…)

See, not ‘phosphoryl’, but ‘**phosphate**’ group.

Phosphoryl is very different group. Cite from IUPAC Nomenclature of organic chemistry, preferred names (2013):

> **P-67.1.4.1.1.2** Fundamental acyl groups for substituent derived from mononuclear noncarbon oxoacids
>
> (…)
>
> $\ce{-P(O)<}$
> phosphoryl

It's the same in inorganic chemistry. E.g. [phosphoryl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphoryl_chloride), $\ce{POCl3}$. Cite from IUPAC Nomenclature of Inorganic chemistry, 2005:

> Table III, *Suffixes and endings*
>
> (…)
>
> oryl
>
> Ending of prefixes for substituent groups formed by removing all hydroxy groups from ‘oric’ acids, e.g. phosphoryl, P(O)[image: ≡], from phosphoric acid.

I honestly don't know why the process of introducing the phosphate group is called phosphorylation. I guess is sounded much better than e.g. ‘phosphatization’ to the term designer, and analogous to e.g. ‘methylation’, but he/she did not realize, that ‘phosphoryl’ already has a (different) meaning. Btw, the $\ce{-P(O)(OH)2}$ group is ‘**phosphono**’ group, see e.g. [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/51616/544) answer or [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/103217/544) question.

#### UPDATE

… and the (di)anionic form of the phosphono group is named **phosphonato** group.

> **P-72.6.1** Prefixes for anionic centers derived from acid characteristic groups
>
> (…)
>
> $\ce{-CO-O^-}$
> carboxylato (preselected prefix)
>
> $\ce{-SO2-O^-}$
> sulfonato (preselected prefix)
>
> $\ce{-P(O)(O^-)2}$
> phosphonato (preselected prefix)
>
> (…)

There's also biochemistry related document<sup>[1]</sup>, effectively discouraging the use of “phosphoryl” for phosphate group names of biochemicals:

> **Phosphoric esters**, $\ce{RO-PO(OH)2}$, are named
> as *O*-substituted phosphoric acids or as substituted alcohols (Table I).
> Thus, choline *O*-(dihydrogen phosphate) and *O*-phosphonocholine are
> both appropriate names. The latter may be contracted to phosphocholine,
> but not changed to phosphorylcholine; “phosphoryl” is defined
> as OP[image: ≡] and requires, if used,
> the naming of all three groups attached to the
> phosphorus atom. However, “phosphoryl” is retained
> in derived terms such as the names of enzymes
> (e.g., phosphorylase) or of processes (e.g.,
> phosphorylation).
>
> (…)

Table I (I won't reproduce it for technical reasons), lists many examples of (1) phosphate names, (2) *O*-phospho/phospho names, (3) systematic names (the first two types marked as recommended for biochemical usage), and (4) abbreviations. No name uses “phosphoryl”; some examples:

- 1. D-Fructose 1,2-bis(phosphate)
  2. 1,6-Di-*O*-phosphono-D-fructose;
     1,6-Bis(phospho)-D-fructose
  3. D-Fructofuranose 1,6-bis(dihydrogen phosphate)
  4. Fructose-1,6-*P*<sub>2</sub>
- 1. D-Glyceraldehyde 3-phosphate
  2. 3-*O*-Phosphono-D-glyceraldehyde;
     3-Phospho-D-glyceraldehyde
  3. 2-Hydroxy-3-oxopropyl dihydrogen phosphate;
     2-Formyl-2-hydroxyethyl dihydrogen phosphate;
     D-Glyceraldehyde 3-(dihydrogen phosphate)
  4. D-Glyceraldehyde-3-*P*
- *(oxidated - carboxylate anionic form of the above aldehyde)*

  1. D-Glycerate 3-phosphate
  2. 3-*O*-Phosphono-D-glycerate;
     3-Phospho-D-glycerate
  3. (*R*)-[2-Hydroxy-3-(phosphonooxy)propanoate];
     (*R*)-[2,3-Dihydroxypropanoate 3-(dihydrogenphosphate)]
  4. D-Glycerate-3-*P*

On the other hand, despite of this recommendation, somewhat related recent document operates with “phosphoryl” name for phosphate unit frivolously.<sup>[2]</sup>

If I borrow the image from the neighbor answer

[image: Fig.2]

these would be properly names **phosphonatooxy** and ***O*-phosphonato**, respectively. And, for protonated non-anionic forms, **phosphonooxy** and ***O*-phosphono**. No “phosphoryl”.

However it's for names where one needs to name these groups as prefixes. The correct name of the structure in the picture still is ethyl **phosphate**.

References:

1. [Nomenclature of Phosphorus-Containing Compounds of Biochemical Importance. (Recommendations 1976)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1184129/). IUPAC-IUB Commission on Biochemical Nomenclature. *Biochem J* **1978**, *171* (1), 1–19.
2. Blackburn, G. M.; Cherfils, J.; Moss, G. P.; Richards, N. G. J.; Waltho, J. P.; Williams, N. H.; Wittinghofer, A. [How to Name Atoms in Phosphates, Polyphosphates, Their Derivatives and Mimics, and Transition State Analogues for Enzyme-Catalysed Phosphoryl Transfer Reactions (IUPAC Recommendations 2016)](https://doi.org/10.1515/pac-2016-0202). *Pure and Applied Chemistry* **2017**, *89* (5), 653–675.

Comment: Thanks. From what you've said I understand that phosphorylation involves the addition, to a molecule,  of a phosphate group not a phosphoryl group.  Any idea why https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorylation   "In chemistry, phosphorylation of a molecule is the attachment of a phosphoryl group.....A phosphoryl group should not be confused with a phosphate group....The phosphoryl group plays the central role in phosphorylation...."      Whereas this other link agrees with you   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_phosphorylation  "...phosphate group..."